# fastSeek method not working in Firefox OS device Spice MIFX1

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, mozilla, firefox-os

I am trying to make an app for Firefox OS where I use the fastSeek method. There is a function which play the audio from beginning as shown below.

```
var tapSound=new Audio("sounds/tap.wav");
function playfrombegin()
{
    tapSound.fastSeek(0);
    tapsound.play();
}
```

And when I press a key this function is called.

This is working just fine in all browsers and the Firefox OS simulator too. But when I install it in my device Spice MIFX1 the function is not working and the audio does not play. But when I comment the line

```
//tapSound.fastSeek(0);
```

It is working just fine. Seems like the device does not know the fastSeek method.

I need to seek the audio to the beginning as the audio may be still playing when I call the function. And when I call the function the audio must start from beginning.

Is this a bug with the device?

If yes, is there an alternate way to play the audio from beginning?

Comment: a lot of the audio API relies on device drivers so, yes, it sounds like a bug. Can you file one here? https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Firefox%20OS I'm not familiar enough to know of a workaround.

Comment: I think it is fixed in Firefox OS ver 2 as said by JulienW below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this as well

```
  var tapSound=new Audio("sounds/tap.wav");

    function playfrombegin()
    {
        tapSound.currentTime = 0;
        tapsound.play();
    }
```

Comment: `tapSound.currentTime=0` Works. It is an alternate way. So don't the firefox OS provide support for fastSeek ?

Answer (score 1):

fastSeek is available since Firefox OS 2.0 (source: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/Firefox_OS/Releases/2.0)

Previous solution should work :)

Which Firefox OS version do you use ?

Comment: I am using firefox version 1.3. Thanks for the information.